# Conditionally use root user in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Say I want to conditionally run as the root user, otherwise run as a user called "node". So it would be something like:

```
if(useRootUser){

  ENV HOME="/root"
  RUN mkdir -p /root/.docker_r2g_cache
  RUN mkdir -p /root/app/node_modules
  WORKDIR /root/app

}
else {

  USER node
  ENV USER="node"
  ENV HOME="/home/node"
  RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.docker_r2g_cache
  RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules
  WORKDIR /home/node/app

}
```

obviously that pseudocode is not correct. What might be the most efficient way to do this?

The only way I can think of doing this is with `--build-arg`.

Something like this:

```
 ARG user, home;

 USER $user
 ENV USER="$user"
 ENV HOME="$home"
 RUN mkdir -p $home/.docker_r2g_cache
 RUN mkdir -p $home/app/node_modules
 WORKDIR $home/app
```

and then using:

```
docker build <tag> --build-arg home="/root" --build-arg user="root"
```

or

```
docker build <tag> --build-arg home="/home/node" --build-arg user="node"
```

is that about right?

Comment: I don't like this.  Nonetheless, it looks correct to me.  Why don't you try it? and if it does not work, you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: This will work. Default values make the load a bit lighter:
`ARG user=${user:-node}`

Comment: @PaulHicks it's simpler than you think - using `ARG user=x`, x is the default value.

Comment: So `ARG user=Paul` will be Joe if `--build-args user=Joe` and Paul if no build-args are provided? Nice.

Comment: yes I am about 99% sure that is correct, I learned that today from someone with a lot of SO points, but haven't tested it personally